# How to group rows with same value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, row

How to group rows with same value in sql?

```
data1 123  12/03/2009
      124  15/09/2009
data2 333  02/09/2010
      323  02/11/2010
      673  02/09/2014
      444  05/01/2010
```

Comment: Can you show the expected result along the query you have tried?

Comment: Please provide the test data and the expected results

Comment: how can i send my query here?

Comment: @g2_player: Click edit button under your question and paste the query then click save. BTW, please show the expected result too.

Comment: @RagingBull: the expected result is a photo. can i upload photos here?

Comment: yes . you can upload images with your question.

Comment: @g2_player: Your reputation will not let you to upload the photo. So upload to some websites and post a link here.

Comment: This is usually done at report level, not by query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(col1 varchar(20),col2 int, col3 varchar(20))
insert into @temp values ('data1', 123 , '12/03/2009'),('data1', 124 , '15/09/2009'),
                        ('data2 ',333  ,'02/09/2010'),('data2 ',323 , '02/11/2010'),
                        ('data2 ',673 , '02/09/2014'),('data2',444 , '05/01/2010')

SELECT 
    (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN col1 ELSE '' END )AS col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM
(                   
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY col2) AS rno,
        col1,col2,col3
    FROM @temp
) As temp
```

This gives the following output

```
col1    col2    col3
---------------------------------
data1   123 12/03/2009
        124 15/09/2009
data2   323 02/11/2010
        333 02/09/2010
        444 05/01/2010
        673 02/09/2014
```

`PARTITION BY` is grouping the data with the given column name, and a row number is generated in that group based on the `order by`.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/417c0/2)

I have created another fiddle based on the schema provided .[fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/4)

Comment: can i e-mail you a photo?

Comment: sure. Or if you want You can upload it with your question.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80 look at my query

Comment: what is rno in your query?

Comment: this is almost correct but my first column was like this 13519

Comment: @g2_player it is row number which i used to find out the duplicate. rno will be generated based on the grouping of col1

Comment: I have created another fiddle based on your schema. check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/4

Comment: @Nithesh I thought it would fail on missing ordering, but it seems there is am implicit ordering that i had not expected. This works fine

Comment: Actually `PARTITION BY` grouping the data with the given column name, and a row number is generated in that group based on the `order by` .

Comment: @Nithesh: can i ask if i add rows? in my fiddle schema you can see Premium, Commission, NetPremium.. can i add the values of each column depending on the partition??

Comment: i think yes you can, but let me see how you expect your result

Comment: @Nithesh: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926367/how-to-sum-rows-according-to-partition-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have multiple same records as in below query. To select the distinct ones, you can either use `GROUP BY`  or `DISTINCT` as below:

**Using GROUP BY:**

```
with datatab as
(
select 'data1' dataa,  123 num,   '12/03/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data1' dataa,  123 num,   '12/03/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data1' dataa,  123 num,   '12/03/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data1' dataa,  124 num,   '15/09/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  333 num,   '02/09/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  323 num,   '02/11/2010' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  673 num,   '02/09/2014' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  444 num,   '05/01/2010' datee from dual 

)
select dataa, num, datee from datatab 
group by dataa, num, datee
order by dataa;
```

**USING DISTINCT:**

```
with datatab as
(
select 'data1' dataa,  123 num,   '12/03/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data1' dataa,  123 num,   '12/03/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data1' dataa,  123 num,   '12/03/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data1' dataa,  124 num,   '15/09/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  333 num,   '02/09/2009' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  323 num,   '02/11/2010' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  673 num,   '02/09/2014' datee from dual union all
select 'data2' dataa,  444 num,   '05/01/2010' datee from dual 

)
select distinct dataa, num, datee from datatab 
order by dataa;
```

For both Queries, `ORIGINAL DATA` is :

```
dataa    | num   | datee
------------------------------
data1    | 123    | 12/03/2009
data1    | 123    | 12/03/2009
data1    | 123    | 12/03/2009
data1    | 124    | 15/09/2009
data2    | 333    | 02/09/2009
data2    | 323    | 02/11/2010
data2    | 673    | 02/09/2014
data2    | 444    | 05/01/2010
```

Query `OUTPUT DATA` is:

```
dataa    | num   | datee
------------------------------
data1    | 123    | 12/03/2009
data1    | 124    | 15/09/2009
data2    | 333    | 02/09/2009
data2    | 323    | 02/11/2010
data2    | 673    | 02/09/2014
data2    | 444    | 05/01/2010
```

**EDIT:**
Refer Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/9  created by Nithesh

This query would obtain the distinct records too:

```
SELECT 
(CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN EndorsementId ELSE '' END )AS col1,
*
FROM
(                   
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EndorsementId ORDER BY PolicyNumber) AS rno,
    *
FROM (select distinct * from [endorsement]  ) a
) As temp1
```

Hope it helps.!

Comment: how can i show you my query?

Comment: @g2_player: Select edit option and add your query with four spaces. You can also put ORIG data and expected OUTPUT data as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: can i e-mail you a photo?

Comment: Not required. Just add the relavant data in your Stack overflow question using EDIT option, so that everyone can help!

Comment: @g2_player: Refer edit at end of my answer based on Nitesh's Fiddle!

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
Select col1, col2, col3 From tblName
Group By col1
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: thanks but some columns has the same value so it is also an incorrect syntax

Comment: could you be more specific? the SQL provided works in my test enviroment

Comment: how can i upload something here?

Comment: @g2_player: You need not upload. Just key in/type in your question!

Comment: -1 what is this invalid answer suppose to do ?

Comment: invalid logic that does not answer the question