# How to sum rows according to partition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum, window-functions

how can you add values within rows according to it's partition and the sum will be placed below each partition (new row/s below each partition will be the container of the sum)?

use the link below:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/4

column names:
Premium,  Commission,  NetPremium

```
    col1    col2   col3
```

data

```
    124    213    producer
     -1     12    producer
```

data2

```
    -1    312    producer
    444    -555  producer
    100    555   producer
```

---

```
    col1    col2   col3
```

data

```
    124    213    producer
     -1     12
    123    225    null     <<<<'result'
```

data2

```
    -1    312    producer
    444    -555  
    100    555
    543    312   null      <<<<'result'
```

Comment: can u post a sample of expected result ?

Comment: it is in excel. how can i send it to you sir?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904192/how-to-group-rows-with-same-value-in-sql/23904402#23904402 and add the output like that. i mean you can type in a sample

Comment: @Nithesh: take a look :D

Comment: hope `cha` gives you the correct answer. Have try like that

Comment: @Nithesh : but I can't add the other columns to my SELECT statement :((

Comment: you can add other columns in your select statement and the group by clause as well, which gives you  the expected result i think

Comment: @Nithesh i have a question http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/42 look at this fiddle and you can see same endoID but different EndoNumber so im askin if how can i clear the row of the same endonumber?? the columns that will only remain are the dates and EndoID..

Comment: Can you post it as a separate question

Comment: i cant post another question i got too much negative votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ROLLUP:

Here is a set with a few columns (Premium only)

```
SELECT 
    (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN EndorsementId ELSE '' END )AS col1,
    rno,
    sum(PREMIUM)
FROM
(                   
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EndorsementId ORDER BY PolicyNumber) AS rno,
        *
    FROM [endorsement]
) As temp1
GROUP by EndorsementId, rno
with rollup
```

And the result:

```
|  COL1 |    RNO | COLUMN_2 |
|-------|--------|----------|
| 13519 |      1 |      750 |
|       |      2 |        0 |
|       |      3 |        0 |
|       | (null) |      750 |
| 13524 |      1 |      157 |
|       |      2 |        0 |
|       |      3 |      158 |
|       |      4 |       16 |
|       | (null) |      331 |
. . . . . . .
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/24)

BTW, the same result can be achieved with Compute BY (it just does not work in the SQL Fiddle):

```
SELECT 
    (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN EndorsementId ELSE '' END )AS col1,
    rno,
    PREMIUM
FROM
(                   
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EndorsementId ORDER BY PolicyNumber) AS rno,
        *
    FROM [endorsement]
) As temp1
ORDER by EndorsementId, rno
COMPUTE SUM(Premium) BY EndorsementId
```

If there is too much trouble for you to ignore the last row generated by ROLLUP then you can use the following statement that will generate you the desired result with group totals. It is a bit long, but does the job well. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/38):

```
SELECT 
    (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN EndorsementId  WHEN 9999999999 THEN 'Total'ELSE '' END )AS [Endorsement ID],
     (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN PolicyNumber  ELSE ''  END )AS [Policy Number],
      (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN InsuredName  ELSE ''  END )AS [Insured Name],
       (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN [temp1].[EffectiveDate]  ELSE ''  END )AS [Effective Date], 
        (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN [temp1].[ExpirationDate]  ELSE ''  END )AS [Expiration Date], 
         (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN [temp1].[EndorsementNumber]  ELSE ''  END )AS [Endorsement Number],
          (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN [temp1].[EffectFromDate]  ELSE ''  END )AS [EffectFrom Date],
           (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN [temp1].[DueDate]  ELSE ''  END )AS [Due Date],
            (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN [temp1].[Producer]  ELSE ''  END )AS [Producer],
             Premium,
              Commission,
               NetPremium AS [Net Premium]          
FROM
(                   
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EndorsementId ORDER BY PolicyNumber) AS rno,
        *
    FROM [endorsement]
UNION ALL
    SELECT
             9999999999 AS rno,
             EndorsementId, 
             '', 
             '', 
             '', 
             '', 
             '',
             '',
             '',
             '',
             SUM(Premium) AS Premium,
             SUM(Commission) AS Commission,
             SUM(NetPremium) AS NetPremium
    FROM [endorsement]
    GROUP BY EndorsementId
) As temp1
ORDER BY EndorsementId, rno
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/29 take a look at my query.. how can you combine the two select statements? thanks

Comment: I think with the `rollup` the last row of the group will be your result

Comment: BTW, the very last row is your `Grand Total`

Comment: HOW CAN I REMOVE THE VERY LAST ROW? :D and how about this columns i can't add this in the SELECT statment? (EndorsementId, PolicyNumber,InsuredName,  EffectiveDate,  ExpirationDate,  EndorsementNumber,EffectFromDate,DueDate, Producer,

Comment: can i need your help? :(

Comment: yes you can! I have updated the answer and included a solution to not use ROLLUP

Comment: hello i have this follow up question can you answer it.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e3e80/37 in this fiddle you can see the total is duplicating.. and it has wrong computation

Comment: total for what? I can't see any duplications

Comment: another question hahaha :) can i remove the the old rows and show only the rows with total.. and also the values of other column shown so per partition/group is equal to 1 row and the value of the PREMIUM COMMISSION and NETPREMIUM is the total of each partition :D thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to `UNION` the total rows to the raw data and order the result in the desired way, directly with the data from the fiddle linked is

```
SELECT 
    (CASE rno WHEN 1 THEN EndorsementId ELSE '' END )AS col1,
    *
FROM
(                   
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EndorsementId 
                              ORDER BY PolicyNumber) AS rno,
        *
    FROM [endorsement]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL As rno
         , EndorsementId, PolicyNumber, InsuredName, EffectiveDate
         , ExpirationDate, EndorsementNumber, EffectFromDate, DueDate, Producer
         , Sum(Premium) Premium
         , Sum(Commission) Commission
         , Sum(NetPremium) NetPremium
    From   [endorsement]
    Group By EndorsementId, PolicyNumber, InsuredName, EffectiveDate
           , ExpirationDate, EndorsementNumber, EffectFromDate, DueDate, Producer
) As temp1
Order By EndorsementId, Coalesce(rno, 999)
```